# shgetvalue runtime error

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm using the below code to read the registry to get the value of EnableLUA

```
LPCTSTR pszSubKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System";
LPCTSTR pszValue = "EnableLUA";
DWORD dwType = 0;
DWORD dwValue = 0;
DWORD dwValueSize = sizeof( DWORD );

if ( ERROR_SUCCESS != SHGetValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, pszSubKey, pszValue, 
    &dwType, &dwValue, &dwValueSize) )
```

I run the above code in admin mode even then am getting runtime error. 
Any other apis available to get this job done. I want to simply check whether EnableLUA value is 0 or 1..
I'm using mingw and LSTATUS is showing as compile time

> error: unkown declararion LSTATUS.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure your program runs as admin? On Vista and later, UAC might be causing program to run as luser, even if you're logged as admin.

Comment: ya I run with UAC turned off.. and more doubt is shgetvalue return value is Lstatus which is showing error in my mingw compiler...

Comment: What is the result of LSTATUS returned?

Comment: no I cant use LSTATUS and showing compiler error in mingw...

Comment: Works for me, as long as `pszValueOn` is a typo and you mean `pszValue`.

Comment: I used RegQueryValue( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\System[shutdownwithoutlogon]"),NULL,&dwType ,0, &dwValueSize); nad even this didnt help me.

Comment: yeah I change it to pszValue. still am gettin an error. how to make LSTATUS work in mingw.

Comment: Where is LSTATUS? If you want to check status code GetLastError

Comment: I couldnt use LSTATUS as am using mingw its showing error.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Mingw doesn't fully support Windows?

LSTATUS is the return type of SHGetValue, so should be defined.  Look in **Shlwapi.h** for the prototype for SHGetValue.

You can probably temporarily change the code to assign the return value from SHGetValue to a variable and print it out.  Then tell us what the value is.  It's probably 5 (*access denied*).

Are you including **Windows.h** AND **Shlwapi.h** in your code?

From MSDN:

**Return value**

Type: *LSTATUS*

Returns ERROR_SUCCESS if successful, or a nonzero error code defined in Winerror.h otherwise. You can use the FormatMessage function with the FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM flag to retrieve a generic description of the error.

Comment: in Mingw SHGetValue is defined as follows.. Its return type is DWORD!!!WINSHLWAPI DWORD WINAPI SHGetValueA(HKEY,LPCSTR,LPCSTR,LPDWORD,LPVOID,LPDWORD);
WINSHLWAPI DWORD WINAPI SHGetValueW(HKEY,LPCWSTR,LPCWSTR,LPDWORD,LPVOID,LPDWORD);

Comment: That's unusual, but fair enough.  LSTATUS is the same as DWORD (both 32-bits.  What is the value returned from SHGetValue?

Comment: Hi Neil I didnt go with SHGetValue. Instead I used RegOpenKeyEx and RegQueryValueEx to do the same. And thanks for the answer. Upvoted..